# Возможно ли установить Callback-функцию при завершении работы скрипта?

Tags: callback, php

Нужно назначить код, который бы автоматически выполнялся в конце работы скрипта. Чтобы работало как директива auto_append _file (авто-подключение файла в конце выполнения скрипта), но с такой разницей:

1. это должна быть callback-функция вместо инклуда файла;
2. устанавливалось во время выполнения, а не через .htaccess

Возможно ли в пхп такое?

---

**Попытка решения (неуд.):** Сначала хотел заюзать деструктор главного объекта (ведь он полюбому выполнится в конце), но все красивое решение развалилось, когда до меня дошло, что деструктируются все остальные объекты, и, когда выполнение доходит до главного деструктора, все нужные объекты уже уничтожены. Поэтому нужнен коллбэк, чтобы выполнился ДО срабатывания всех деструкторов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Повесьте обработчик на [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: Благодарю! То, что надо! А я и не нашел...

Comment: да, бывает :)